# Elastic Search, creating index with sources and settings by Rest Java Client

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create index following this guide: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-create-index.html#_providing_the_whole_source
The problem is, that index is not created properly. Looks like whole `settings` section as well as `completion` type is ignored.

My json file:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 3,
        "number_of_replicas": 1,
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {},
            "analyzer": {
                "keyword_analyzer": {
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding",
                        "trim"
                    ],
                    "char_filter": [],
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
            "properties": {
                "first": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keywordstring": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer"
                        },
                        "completion": {
                            "type": "completion"
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": "standard"
                },
                "second": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keywordstring": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer"
                        },
                        "completion": {
                            "type": "completion"
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": "standard"
                },
                "third": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keywordstring": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer"
                        },
                        "completion": {
                            "type": "completion"
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": "standard"
                },
                "fourth": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keywordstring": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer"
                        },
                        "completion": {
                            "type": "completion"
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": "standard"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Java code:

```
CreateIndexRequest indexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest(ESClientConfiguration.INDEX_NAME);
        URL url = Resources.getResource(TERYT_INDEX_CONFIGURATION_FILE_NAME);

        return Try.of(() -> Resources.toString(url, Charsets.UTF_8))
                  .map(jsonIndexConfiguration -> indexRequest.source(jsonIndexConfiguration, XContentType.JSON))
                  .get();

createIndexRequest.setTimeout(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(2));

        Try.of(() -> client.indices().create(createIndexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT))...
```

Index is created but when I look into Index Metadata, it looks completly wrong:

```
{
    "state": "open",
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "creation_date": "1556379012380",
            "number_of_shards": "1",
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "uuid": "L5fmkrjeQ6eKmuDyZ3MP3g",
            "version": {
                "created": "7000099"
            },
            "provided_name": "my_index"
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
            "properties": {
                "first": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "ignore_above": 256,
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "second": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "ignore_above": 256,
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "third": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "ignore_above": 256,
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "fourth": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "ignore_above": 256,
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aliases": [],
    "primary_terms": {
        "0": 1
    },
    "in_sync_allocations": {
        "0": [
            "Cx6tBeohR8mzbTO74dwsCw",
            "FcTUhpb_SL2LiaEyy_uwkg"
        ]
    }
}
```

There is only 1 shard without replicas, I also don't see any informations about `completion` type. Does someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Any chance your index already exists ?

Comment: No :/ I removed whole index right now

Comment: Do you catch any exception? BTW which version is that?

Comment: There is no exception, the Index is created fine, but with wrong settings. This is 7.0.0 version

Comment: So I can tell you that your index is not created with those index settings. I think that the code you are running after creates documents, right? Those documents create the index with default mapping. Check your code again.

Comment: Alright, I will investigate it once again

Comment: You are right, I encountered the real problem: `reason=Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this line:

```
    Try.of(() -> client.indices().create(createIndexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT))...
```

is hiding an important exception.
Here you are using elasticsearch 7.0.0 which does not allow anymore giving a "type" name in your mapping.

Instead of

```
"mappings": {
    "my_type": {
        "properties": {
```

You should write:

```
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
```

Because of the exception and the fact that probably after index creation you are indexing some documents, default index settings and mapping are applied.
Which explains what you are seeing.

You need to fix your index settings first.
I'd recommend doing that in Kibana dev console.